# Skip a specific row in Spark Dataset using Flatmap function when there is error/exception in row flatten logic

Tags: apache-spark

How to skip the specific row in Spark `Dataset<Row>` when there is an error in a row flattening into multiple records, and continue to process the next rows in the dataset.

Example: Lines to word mapping spark job with dataset API with FlatMapFunction, if any line have word "ERROR", want to skip the line altogether and continue process the next lines.

Line 1: `I AM A JAVA PROGRAMMER` - can be processed.

Line 2: `THERE IS AN ERROR IN THIS LINE` - skip this complete line including words within it as it contains 'ERROR' word.

Line 3: `CODE LOOKS BETTER WORK BETTER` - can be processed

Output should be: `I, AM, A, JAVA, PROGRAMMER ,CODE, LOOKS, BETTER, WORK, BETTER`

https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/61/Spark/StructuredStreamingWordCountApplication_2.html

**Sample Code:**

```
Dataset<String> inputLines = sparkSession.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "http://127.0.0.1:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "sampleTopic")
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as(Encoders.STRING());
        inputLines.printSchema();

       Dataset<String> inputWords = inputLines.flatMap(new TestMapper(), Encoders.STRING()).as(Encoders.STRING());


        inputWords.writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .option("checkpointLocation", "D:\\tmp\\")
                .start()
                .awaitTermination();

public class TestMapper implements FlatMapFunction<String, String> {
@Override
public Iterator<String> call(String line) throws Exception {
    return flattenWord(line);

}

private Iterator<String> flattenWord(String line) {
    if(line.contains("ERROR"))
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad word****************");
    return Arrays.asList(line.split(" ") ).iterator();
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Lamanus, Didn't get u. Can u elaborate what additional information required

Comment: Any code have you made? Any try.

Comment: Lamanus, Updated the code. Provide provide your inputs to solve the problem statement.

Comment: What exception occur with your sample code? Which part is the problem?

Comment: Same like in mentioned code snippet flattenword(), exception could any runtime exception.

Comment: You mean this `throw new RuntimeException("Bad word****************");`??

Comment: Yes, Any Runtime exception while building flatten record and returning iterator. just to illustrate the problem added explicit exception in flattenword method.

Comment: @KCCK instead of throwing exception just return an empty array or iterator. Any specific reason you are throwing exception?

Comment: @Izhar - In original case I am returning empty/default object and filtering empty/default objects. this works,but the point is my flatten logic results into 1lac of records for each row, I dont want to process the flatten the records further if any exception occurs. I mean that row should be completely skipped if any of its flatten record is failed.